# Duplicate entries in switch ARP table

Tags: arp

A server is showing twice or more on my L2 switch ARP table

Same IP address, mac address, and ethernet port.

What could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Describe the switch?

Comment: It's a 3COM 5500G-EI 48-Port - Thanks

Comment: Are you viewing the table by MAC address or port?

Comment: I am using the command "display arp" and it gives me the IP address, MAC address and switch port. Sometimes I will get duplicate entries.